# Which scripture mentions the verse "Sanghe Shakti Kali Yuge" used by RSS?

Tags: identification-request, ganesha, kali-yuga, durga

The verse "Sanghe Shakti Kali Yuge" (संघे शक्ति कलियुगे ) means "Unity is strength in Kali Yuga". It's mostly used by RSS(which is also known as Sangha) and other Sangh Parivar organizations emphasizing the importance of unity in Kali Yuga.

Though in this video titled [Praying to Devi Chandi & Vinayaka give immediate benefits in Kali Yuga](https://youtu.be/atKF4QUEtJE) by Goverdhan Math Shankaracharya Ji, He uses this verse to describe how worship of  Devi Chandi/Durga who is combined Shaktis of all Devas and Lord Ganesha who is the lord of Ganas, give benefits easily in Kali Yuga as both are deities of unity.

He further describes how both Ganesha and Chandi are deities of Sangha, that is unity.

So my question is, what is the scriptural basis of this verse?

Comment: There is no tag for Goddess Chandika, so I had to add Durga tag instead. Interesting question BTW.

Comment: @Rickross thanks! Well I have even seen this verse on Vaishnava/ISKCON websites. But it seems like RSS is the only organization which uses it actively.